# Using firebase to login with ejs partials

Tags: node.js, firebase, backend

Disclaimer: I am new with nodejs learned it just recently, so it's possible that what I am trying to do isn't optimal and it's better to do it in another way.

I am trying to login with the firebase API key:https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
in an ejs file and I don't know how to do it.
I have the key to put at the bottom of the page but I don't manage to get the script from the URL.

If it matters
I am running express server on nodejs:

```
const express  = require("express")
const app_port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = express()
const user_controller= require("./userController") //a file to handle user logins/signups
const admin= require("./firebase-admin")() //firebase admin SDK

app.set("view engine", "ejs")    

app.get("/",(req, res) => {
    res.render("index", {title: "hello user"})
})
```

I have a form input in a ejs file (with user name and password):

```
<form id="login_form" method="post" action="/login">
              <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..." required/>
              <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..." required/>
              <button type="submit" value="Login to Account">Login to Account</button> 
              <a href="forgotpassword">forgot password?</a><br><br>
</form>
```

according to that guide I need to add https://www.gstatic.com/fireba)js/7.14.3/firebase-app.js" 
I managed to do in pure html, but can't add  to an ejs file cause it works with <% %> tags  instead of  but then I didn't find how to import a js file from an url.

most of my ejs files work with the database so if I want to use that app I want to post it in one file and then import that partial ejs file into them.

Answer (score 1):

NVM I managed to fix it with middleware:

> app.use("/",express.static("js"))